# Firestore Security Rules Shared Document by Group

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a situation where a user can create a doc and then share it with a group of other users. They could share it to multiple different groups. I don't know how to set a rule for this.

Here is the database structure:

[image]

So in the group you have a list of docs that have been shared to it. My app loads the group that a user is in, then wants to load all the docs in the documents array. I need a way server side to say that this is OK. Up until now only the owner of the doc can read it.

I put a field in each doc that contains ids for each group its shared to. I think I want to say "check if the user is a member of any groups in the sharedToGroups" list but I can't work out how to do that unless I maintain another list somewhere say in the userProfile doc that has a list of circles the user is a member of. Even then I'd be trying to compare 2 lists and I'm not sure I can do that client side.

It would be nice to be able to get the group Id somehow from where the request is being issued from and just see if that is in the sharedToGroups array.

Any help or comments on how this can be achieved would be greatly appreciated, maybe it needs a different db structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. Not sure if its the correct protocol here (not a professional programmer or experienced Stack Overflower) but it might help someone.

I ended up adding a field in the user_profiles document that has a list of each group they are in. This list needs to be maintained as I create and add / remove people from groups along with the members list in the group itself.

The benefit of this is that I can use the users id from the request object to get that document from the data base in the security rule. I then have a 'sharedToGroup' array in the doc I'm trying to access and a "inGroups" array in the user_profile that I can access also. Then I use the hasAny operator to compare the two arrays and allow access if the sharedToGroup array has any values from the inGroups array.

My rule becomes:

```
  match /_group/{groupId}{
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
      allow read: if isOwner() 
      || resource.data.sharedToGroup.hasAny(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_profiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data['inGroups']);
      allow write: if isOwner();
    }
```

Only thing left to do is to secure the user_profiles doc to make sure not even the user can write to it since I don't want someone manually adding groups into their array.

I hope this might help someone someday - like I said I'm a not a pro here so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an approach of this sort:

I am not sure if this will help you but off the top of my head maybe you could enable permissions on `firestore` for the `group` document. As in, in the rules, for the group set up a function that validates the user with the user ID stored in the document with the ID attached in the auth via the `firebase auth`

Therefore, rather than trying to restrict access per document, restrict access per group.

Comment: Hi Lakindu, thanks for the response. Are you able to post some pseudo code to show what you mean?

Comment: I added a field to my user_profile doc called groups. When you join a group it adds the id of that group to the groups array. Now I have read access if you are the owner OR if in your user_profile you have the id of the group in your groups field


resource.data.sharedToGroup.hasAny(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_profiles/$(request.auth.uid)).data['groups']);

This seems to be working nicely in the online emulator but on my local emulator it gives me an error but then actually looks like it fetches the doc anyway.